# Distinct records form the string column using pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like the following:

```py
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    (22,'fl1.variant,fl2.variant,fl3.control','xxx','yyy','zzz'),
    (23,'fl1.variant,fl2.neither,fl3.control','xxx','yyy','zzz'),
    (24,'fl4.variant,fl2.variant,fl4.variant','xxx1','yyy1','zzz1'),
    (25,'fl3.control,fl3.control,fl3.variant','xxx1','yyy1','zzz1')
])

df = rdd.toDF(['Date','Type','Data1','Data2','Data3'])
```

**sample data :**

| Date | Type | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | fl1.variant,fl2.variant,fl3.control | xxx | yyy | zzz |
| 23 | fl1.variant,fl2.neither,fl3.control | xxx | yyy | zzz |
| 24 | fl4.variant,fl2.variant,fl4.variant | xxx1 | yyy1 | zzz1 |
| 25 | fl3.control,fl3.control,fl3.variant | xxx1 | yyy1 | zzz1 |

I need to identify the distinct values of `Type` column data based on `Data1`, `Data2` and `Data3` columns. `Type` column's datatype is string separated by `,`.

Based on `Data1`, `Data2`, `Data3`, I need to combine all the data and identify the unique values of `Type` column.

**expected output :**

| Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | Type_list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | yyy | zzz | [fl1.variant,fl2.variant,fl3.control, fl2.neither] |
| xxx1 | yyy1 | zzz1 | [fl4.variant,fl2.variant,fl3.control,fl3.variant] |

I tried like below but could not get the expected distinct values

```py
df1 = df.sort("Data1","Data2","Data3","Type"). \
    groupBy("Data1","Data2","Data3"). \
    agg(func.collect_set("Type").cast(func.StringType())). \
    withColumnRenamed("CAST(collect_set(Type) AS STRING)", "Type_list")
```

| Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | Type_list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | yyy | zzz | [fl1.variant,fl2.variant,fl3.control, fl1.variant, fl2.neither,fl3.control] |
| xxx1 | yyy1 | zzz1 | [fl4.variant,fl2.variant,fl4.variant, fl3.control,fl3.control,fl3.variant] |

```py
df2 = df1.select("Data1","Data2","Data3",func.array_distinct(func.split("Type_list" , ",")))
```

| Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | array_distinct(split(Type_list, ,, -1)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | yyy | zzz | [[fl1.variant, fl2.variant, fl3.control, fl1.variant, fl2.neither, fl3.control]] |
| xxx1 | yyy1 | zzz1 | [[fl4.variant, fl2.variant, fl4.variant, fl3.control, fl3.control, fl3.variant]] |

Comment: I would like to know, if one of the group by column has null values so it will written another row or record. So how to flatten those records also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first `split` then `array_distinct(flatten(collect_list()))`

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('type_split', func.split('type', ',')). \
    groupBy('data1','data2','data3'). \
    agg(func.array_distinct(func.flatten(func.collect_list('type_split'))).alias('type_list')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----+-----+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
# |data1|data2|data3|type_list                                           |
# +-----+-----+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
# |xxx  |yyy  |zzz  |[fl1.variant, fl2.variant, fl3.control, fl2.neither]|
# |xxx1 |yyy1 |zzz1 |[fl4.variant, fl2.variant, fl3.control, fl3.variant]|
# +-----+-----+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I would like to know if one of the group by column has null values so it will written another row or record. How to flatten those records also .

Comment: My thoughts here are before group by we need to handle this scenario